# Build flavor: Suppress pseudo error "Cannot resolve method"

Tags: java, android

## Motivation (feel free to skip)

I am diving into Espresso's [IdlingResource concept](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource.html) and are currently more than displeased with the options I have to use `IdlingResource` inside my production code. I know there is an [article](https://www.philosophicalhacker.com/post/psa-dont-use-esprsso-idling-resources-like-this/) showing a way how I could relieve this issue by various ways or using DI like Dagger2 or AspectJ etc., but I thoroughly considered those variants and dismissed them. (This is my motivation, not a discussion about the decision please)

## Problem (feel free to solve :) )

The best solution for me to get `IdleResource` in my code without mixing too many responsibilities is to create a dummy class `UILock` (not an interface) with two different implementations, one in production code and one in test.

The prod one `src/main/java...`

```
package my.application.something;    

import android.util.Log;

public class UILock
{

    public static void Lock()
    {
        Log.i("REAL", "REAL");
    }

    public static void Unlock()
    {
        Log.i("REAL", "REAL");
    }

}
```

the test one `src/androidTest/java...`

```
package my.application.something;    

import android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResource;
import android.support.test.espresso.idling.CountingIdlingResource;
import android.util.Log;

public class UILock
{
    private static CountingIdlingResource con = new CountingIdlingResource("RES");

    public static void Lock()
    {
        con.increment();

        Log.i("MOCK", "MOCK");
    }

    public static void Unlock()
    {
        con.decrement();
        Log.i("MOCK", "MOCK");
    }


    public static IdlingResource GetIdle()
    {
        return con;
    }
}
```

What this actually does is to create some compile time polymorphism here.

In my tests I write something like

```
Espresso.registerIdlingResources( UILock.GetIdle());
```

and it works because the `debug` variant has the `GetIdle` method implemented.

This concept does actually work fine, the debug configuration compiles well, test run etc, but there is one issue: Android Studio marks the `GetIdle` method with an error "Cannot resolve method". Which is technically wrong IMHO. My build variant is set debug so that this method exist actually.

Is there a way to solve this? Can I suppress the generated pseudo-error? I obviously cannot expose this method in my production variant of `UILock` because it returns an `IdlingResource` which is not compiled into production (that was the entire purpose).

Comment: As this is debug code, perhaps reflection can help to access the function. Not exactly what you are looking for, but it is a viable workaround.

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani not exactly but is probably a viable solution. Maybe someone has another answer but yours is still valuable never the less. Thank you :)